# Providing my own list view for a prefrence activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, preferences

I have  a class which extends from `ListView`. I added some extra functionality(drag and drop) for this new class. My question is there any way i can use this extended `ListView` class in a preference activity.

I need to provide drag and drop functionality for  a legacy preference activity.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if it's possible to open an arbitrary activity from a clicked item in a preference activity?  If so, you need to do two things.  First, add a PreferenceScreen item to your preferences xml file:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="CUSTOM_ACTIVITY_KEY"
    android:title="Title"
    android:summary="Summary" />
```

Then in your settings activity's onCreate:

```
Preference pref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("CUSTOM_ACTIVITY_KEY");
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomActivity.class);
if (pref != null)
{
    pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference)
        {
            startActivity(intent);

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is what @jkv asked for, but it sure helped me :D

Comment: Thanks Josh for you response. But my requirement is some what different. As per my understanding, android framework creates a listview to display the prefrence items supplied to the preference activity(Preference activity extends list activity). My query is ; is it possible to provide our own listview subclass to replace the Listview class used by the preference activity.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe it's possible to insert your own list implementation.  See my other answer for a "last resort."

Answer (score 0):

If running a custom activity off of a PreferenceScreen item isn't enough, the only other option I could think of is to roll your own Preferences implementation.  Someone else should correct me if I'm mistaken, but I think it might be possible to pull the [Preferences source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/android/preference) and modify accordingly.

Comment: Josh , thanks for the response. I got an idea but not sure if it will work . Create a new layout file with my extended listview and on the onCreate of my prefrence activity call setContentView(mynewlayout). If you check PrefrenceActivity's onCreate , they are setting a layout which contains the listview.

Comment: If you extended ListView, and put a `<com.myapp.MyListView>' in your custom layout, with id `@android:id/list`, you might be able to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

I came across another API in

```
android.preference.PreferenceScreen.bind(ListView listView)
```

Binds a `ListView` to the preferences contained in this `PreferenceScreen` via `getRootAdapter()`.
So after inflating the layout file, we will be able to attach the our custom `listview` to this the `preferenceScreen` of the activity.